# How To Set Widget ListTile Hidden

Tags: android, flutter, dart, hide

im trying to set hidden widget `ListTile` if `SharedPreferences` Getting Null Data , i have try to using `Visibility` and i getting error like this

> type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

My `Widget build(BuildContext context)`

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Drawer(
        child: new ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        new DrawerHeader(
          child: new Text("Menu"),
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
        ),
        new ListTile(
          title: new Text("Profile"),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => new ProfileScreen()));
          },
        ),
        new ListTile(
          title: new Text("Proposal List"),
          onTap: () {
            visibleMethod();
          },
        ),
        //MY PROBLEM HERE
        Visibility(
          visible: true, 
          child: listTileAju()),

        new ListTile(
          title: new Text("Sign Out"),
          onTap: () async {
            SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
            pref.remove("authorization");
            pref.remove("is_login");
            Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext ctx) => LoginPage()));
          },
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
```

And `My Widget listTileAju()`

```
  listTileAju() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      roleAju = (pref.getStringList('role_aju') ?? 'Something Went Wrong');
    });
    if (roleAju != null) {
      Visibility(
        visible: true,
        child: new ListTile(
          title: new Text("Aju List"),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            Navigator.push(context,
                new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new AjuScreen()));
          },
        ),
      );
    } else {
      Visibility(
        visible: false,
        child: new ListTile(
          title: new Text("Aju List"),
          onTap: null,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

And i hope the widget ListTile can be Hidden if SharedPreferences Getting Null Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code:-

```
bool isShowListTile;

Widget listTileAju(){
  Visibility(
    visible: isShowListTile,
    child: new ListTile(
      title: new Text("Aju List"),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Navigator.push(context,
            new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new AjuScreen()));
      },
    ),
  );
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  roleAju = (pref.getStringList('role_aju') ?? 'Something Went Wrong');
  if (roleAju != null) {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        isShowListTile = true;
      });
    }
  } else {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        isShowListTile = false;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks dude, i have try your code and little customization and this is work ! i create a new function and i call in ```initState()``` big thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your listTileAju is async, so it become Future and widget can't be future.

Simplest solution is that you have to load data in initState and then you have to use that data here to avoid async.